# Multiple header/nested column name in Excel using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested, data-preprocessing

I want to convert/read an excel file that has at least 3 headers. I've searched some solutions about nested columns that can use `header=[0,1]` to read excel file when it has two row of header. But my file has 3 headers. When I use `header=[0,2]`, it didn't read it as I expected. Below is the example of the data, it has three headers.

[image]

But when I read it with `df_test = pd.read_excel("testing_column.xlsx", header=[0,2])`
It only showed two headers (the first one and the third one)

[image]

Does anyone has any suggestion on how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: `headers=[0,1,2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the answer as you just need to include the middle row as well, by specifying 0 and 2 it had accounted for the first and third row as the header, if you want to include the second one as well you can refer to it by index 1:

```
df_test = pd.read_excel("testing_column.xlsx", header=[0,1,2])
```